# How can I declare BufferGeometryUtils.js to three.d.ts

Tags: three.js, typescript

I do not to refactor all my code to improve performance. I found BufferGeometryUtils in three.js example directory which  enables convert existing geometries to buffer geometry. My question is how can I declare this function to three.d.ts?
Source code of BufferGeometryUtils.js:

```
/**
 * @author spite / http://www.clicktorelease.com/
 * @author mrdoob / http://mrdoob.com/
 */

THREE.BufferGeometryUtils = {

fromGeometry: function geometryToBufferGeometry( geometry, settings ) {

    if ( geometry instanceof THREE.BufferGeometry ) {

        return geometry;

    }

    settings = settings || { 'vertexColors': THREE.NoColors };

    var vertices = geometry.vertices;
    var faces = geometry.faces;
    var faceVertexUvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs;
    var vertexColors = settings.vertexColors;
    var hasFaceVertexUv = faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].length > 0;

    var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    bufferGeometry.attributes = {

        position: {
            itemSize: 3,
            array: new Float32Array( faces.length * 3 * 3 )
        },
        normal: {
            itemSize: 3,
            array: new Float32Array( faces.length * 3 * 3 )
        }

    }

    var positions = bufferGeometry.attributes.position.array;
    var normals = bufferGeometry.attributes.normal.array;

    if ( vertexColors !== THREE.NoColors ) {

        bufferGeometry.attributes.color = {
            itemSize: 3,
            array: new Float32Array( faces.length * 3 * 3 )
        };

        var colors = bufferGeometry.attributes.color.array;

    }

    if ( hasFaceVertexUv === true ) {

        bufferGeometry.attributes.uv = {
            itemSize: 2,
            array: new Float32Array( faces.length * 3 * 2 )
        };

        var uvs = bufferGeometry.attributes.uv.array;

    }

    var i2 = 0, i3 = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i < faces.length; i ++ ) {

        var face = faces[ i ];

        var a = vertices[ face.a ];
        var b = vertices[ face.b ];
        var c = vertices[ face.c ];

        positions[ i3     ] = a.x;
        positions[ i3 + 1 ] = a.y;
        positions[ i3 + 2 ] = a.z;

        positions[ i3 + 3 ] = b.x;
        positions[ i3 + 4 ] = b.y;
        positions[ i3 + 5 ] = b.z;

        positions[ i3 + 6 ] = c.x;
        positions[ i3 + 7 ] = c.y;
        positions[ i3 + 8 ] = c.z;

        var na = face.vertexNormals[ 0 ];
        var nb = face.vertexNormals[ 1 ];
        var nc = face.vertexNormals[ 2 ];

        normals[ i3     ] = na.x;
        normals[ i3 + 1 ] = na.y;
        normals[ i3 + 2 ] = na.z;

        normals[ i3 + 3 ] = nb.x;
        normals[ i3 + 4 ] = nb.y;
        normals[ i3 + 5 ] = nb.z;

        normals[ i3 + 6 ] = nc.x;
        normals[ i3 + 7 ] = nc.y;
        normals[ i3 + 8 ] = nc.z;

        if ( vertexColors === THREE.FaceColors ) {

            var fc = face.color;

            colors[ i3     ] = fc.r;
            colors[ i3 + 1 ] = fc.g;
            colors[ i3 + 2 ] = fc.b;

            colors[ i3 + 3 ] = fc.r;
            colors[ i3 + 4 ] = fc.g;
            colors[ i3 + 5 ] = fc.b;

            colors[ i3 + 6 ] = fc.r;
            colors[ i3 + 7 ] = fc.g;
            colors[ i3 + 8 ] = fc.b;

        } else if ( vertexColors === THREE.VertexColors ) {

            var vca = face.vertexColors[ 0 ];
            var vcb = face.vertexColors[ 1 ];
            var vcc = face.vertexColors[ 2 ];

            colors[ i3     ] = vca.r;
            colors[ i3 + 1 ] = vca.g;
            colors[ i3 + 2 ] = vca.b;

            colors[ i3 + 3 ] = vcb.r;
            colors[ i3 + 4 ] = vcb.g;
            colors[ i3 + 5 ] = vcb.b;

            colors[ i3 + 6 ] = vcc.r;
            colors[ i3 + 7 ] = vcc.g;
            colors[ i3 + 8 ] = vcc.b;

        }

        if ( hasFaceVertexUv === true ) {

            var uva = faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ i ][ 0 ];
            var uvb = faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ i ][ 1 ];
            var uvc = faceVertexUvs[ 0 ][ i ][ 2 ];

            uvs[ i2     ] = uva.x;
            uvs[ i2 + 1 ] = uva.y;

            uvs[ i2 + 2 ] = uvb.x;
            uvs[ i2 + 3 ] = uvb.y;

            uvs[ i2 + 4 ] = uvc.x;
            uvs[ i2 + 5 ] = uvc.y;

        }

        i3 += 9;
        i2 += 6;

    }

    bufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere();

    return bufferGeometry;

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have the [THREE.js definition from Definitely Typed](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/threejs/three.d.ts), you can extend the declaration to include the additional `BufferGeometryUtils` like so:

```
declare module THREE {
    export class GeometryBufferUtils {
        fromGeometry(geometry, settings) : any;
    }
}

var bufferUtils = new THREE.GeometryBufferUtils();
var example = bufferUti
```

In this example, I have just extended the existing `THREE` module declaration with a new class named `GeometryBufferUtils` - you can then add the definition of each method - including any type information that is relevant.

I can't post the whole definition here as there is a limit to answer lengths, but you should be able to start with this example and extend it to cover the features you want. You can also tighten the definitions, which in the example above are quite loose (i.e. the parameters are currently `any` type, but you could type them like this:

```
fromGeometry(geometry: THREE.BufferGeometry, settings) : THREE.BufferGeometry;
```